# Hangman game (GUI) in Python giving TypeError

Tags: python, class, user-interface, python-3.x

I created a Hangman class and a HangmanGUI class for a final project I am doing for a introductory python class. I'm sorry if I am making amateur mistakes but I do not have a very strong background in coding. Every time my partner and I run the GUI class, we get this error:

```
    self.__letterVar.set(self.__ans.getAnswer())
TypeError: set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

Here is the hangman class:

```
from random import *

FOUR = 4

class Hangman:

  # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Constructor
  def __init__(self):
    self.__theWord = ''
    self.__indexList = []
    self.__answer = '_ _ _ _ _ _'
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Accessors
  def getTheWord(self):
    return self.__theWord
  def getIndexList(self):
    return self.__indexList
  def getAnswer(self):
    return self.__answer
  def startFruit(self):
    randNumber = randint(0,FOUR)
    fruit = open("fruits.txt", 'r')
    fruitList = fruit.read().splitlines()
    self.__theWord = fruitList[randNumber]
    return self.__theWord
  def startVege(self):
    randNumber = randint(0,FOUR)
    vege = open("veges.txt", 'r')
    vegeList = vege.read().splitlines()
    self.__theWord = vegeList[randNumber]
    return self.__theWord
  def startName(self):
    randNumber = randint(0,FOUR)
    name = open("names.txt", 'r')
    nameList = name.read().splitlines()
    self.__theWord = nameList[randNumber]
    return self.__theWord
  # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Mutators
  def find(self, answerWord, inputLetter):
    if inputLetter in answerWord:
      self.__indexList = [index for index, letter in enumerate(answerWord) if letter ==         inputLetter]
    else:
      self.__indexList = []

  def set (self, inputLetter):
    newString = ""
    textList = list(self.__answer)
    self.__indexList = self.getIndexList()
    location = self.__indexList
    for aNum in location:
        textList[aNum * 2] = inputLetter 
        newString = ''.join(textList)
        self.__answer = newString

  def reset(self):
    self.__answer = '_ _ _ _ _ _' 
  # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # toString()
  def__str__(self):
    return "Current answer is: %s" % self.__answer

'''
def main():
  game = Hangman()
  keyWord = game.startFruit()
  letter = input("enter letter")
  while letter:
    game.find(keyWord, letter)
    game.set(letter)
    print(game)
    letter = input("enter letter")
main()
'''
```

In the same folder there are several files named Fruits, Veges and Names and each file has about 5-6 six letter words in their respective category. I wanted to have the program open and read the file and extract one word randomly in a list.

We tested out our hangman class and we think it works fine but I think our problem stems from our HangmanGUI class.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
from hangman import *

FOUR = 4 
class HangmanUI(Frame):

  def __init__(self):
    Frame.__init__(self)
    self.master.title("Hangman")
    self.grid()
    self.__label = Label(self, text = "Let's play Hangman!")
    self.__label2 = Label(self, text = "Please choose a category!")
    self.__label2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    self.__buttonPane = Frame(self)
    self.__buttonPane.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    # created a model of the hangman class
    self.__ans = Hangman()
    self.__fruitButton= Button(self.__buttonPane, text = 'Fruits', command =     self.startFruit)
    self.__nameButton = Button(self.__buttonPane, text = 'Names' , command = self.startName)
    self.__vegeButton = Button(self.__buttonPane, text = 'Veges', command = self.startVege)
    self.__fruitButton.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    self.__vegeButton.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    self.__nameButton.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    self.__label.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)
    #to change later so if shuffles images 1-10 with each error (for loop)
    self.__image = PhotoImage(file = "0.gif")
    self.__imageLabel = Label(self, image = self.__image)
    self.__imageLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    self.__letterLabel = Label(self, text = "Please submit a letter to play!")
    # instead of the submit button, tried using enter instead for now
    self.__letterVar= StringVar
    #self.__letterEntry = Entry(self, textvariable = self.__letterVar) # commented out this line, maybe i shouldn't have?
    self.__letterEntry = Entry(self, width = 10)
    self.__letterEntry.bind('<Return>', self.set)
    self.__letterLabel.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
    self.__letterEntry.grid(row = 5, column = 0)

    self.__value = Label(self, textvariable = self.__letterVar)
    self.__value.grid(row= 6, column = 0)


    #creates nested frame 
    self.__letterPane = Frame(self)
    self.__letterPane.grid(row = 7, column = 0)
    self.__letter1 = Label(self.__letterPane, text = '_  _  _  _  _  _')
    self.__letter1.grid(row = 7, column = 0)
  def startFruit(self):
    self.__ans.startFruit()
  def startVege(self):
    self.__ans.startVege()
  def startName(self):
    self.__ans.startName()
  def set(self,event):
    guessWord = self.__ans.getTheWord()
    entryLetter = self.__letterEntry.get()
    self.__ans.find(guessWord, entryLetter)
    newValue = self.__letterEntry.get()
    self.__ans.set(newValue)
    # display new value in letterVar
    # this is where the program crashes
    self.__letterVar.set(self.__ans.getAnswer())
    # invoke delete() to clear entry box
    self.__letterEntry.delete(0,END)


def main():
  HangmanUI().mainloop()
main()
```

Sorry for the long code, this is my first time posting here and we're both really stressed out because its finals week at our university and we've been frantically trying to put this together. We're both aren't comp sci majors so this has been a fairly difficult process.

We weren't sure how we should go about calling the Hangman class and use methods from the Hangman class in the GUI. As of right now, we're getting the error I stated above and we're not sure how we can fix it. The program crashes towards the end of the GUI class at def set(self, event):

If anyone can provide any insight and tips, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's absolutely no need to be making all those attributes "private".

Comment: Put `()` after `StringVar`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Please read the PEP8 at http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ before returning assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `__letterVar` an *instance* of `StringVar`:

```
self.__letterVar = StringVar()
```

otherwise the `set()` method on it is unbound and won't get the automatic `self` first argument.

Your code assigned it as the class, not a new instance, instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed our little error but we still haven't gotten the entire thing to work together. Right now when put letters in the entry box, it doesnt really do anything yet but thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I just accepted! Right now we're still not able to get the game to do what we want it to. Do you think you can help out a little more?

Comment: Try working it out on your own first. If you have *specific* problems, I suggest you ask a new question (having searched for previous answers first, of course).